# TextView not Displaying Seekbar

Tags: android, view, textview, android-seekbar

I just had this issue now and I can't figure out how to solve this. I created an app which can calculate the average of four subjects (Science, Mathematics, English, and Programming). The user can input the student's grade using a seekbar (the minimum value of seekbar is 50%). I also added toggle buttons that can make subject/s of choice included or not. The problem is when I ran the app, the textview (Which should be the one who displays the progress of seekbar) is not displaying the right value when I move the seek bar. It stays at 50. Did I did something wrong? This is my code by the way

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.elijah.comp3labexercise9.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Student Grade Evaluation"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekSci"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggleSci"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:max="50"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToogleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleSci"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/seekSci"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/textView"
    android:textOff="Not Included"
    android:textOn="Included"
    android:checked="false" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekMath"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekSci"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekSci"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekSci"
    android:max="50"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToogleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleMath"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/seekMath"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/toggleSci"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/toggleSci"
    android:textOff="Not Included"
    android:textOn="Included"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Science: 50%"
    android:id="@+id/txtSci"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/toggleSci"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekSci"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekSci" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Mathematics: 50%"
    android:id="@+id/txtMath"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/toggleMath"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekMath"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekMath" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToogleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleEng"
    android:layout_below="@id/toggleMath"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/toggleMath"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/toggleMath"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:textOff="Not Included"
    android:textOn="Included"
    android:checked="false" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekEng"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toggleEng"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekMath"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekMath"
    android:max="50"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="English: 50%"
    android:id="@+id/txtEng"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/toggleEng"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekEng"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekEng" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToogleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleProg"
    android:layout_below="@id/toggleEng"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/toggleEng"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/toggleEng"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:textOff="Not Included"
    android:textOn="Included"
    android:checked="false" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekProg"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/toggleProg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekEng"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekEng"
    android:max="50"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Programming: 50%"
    android:id="@+id/txtProg"
    android:layout_above="@id/seekProg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/seekProg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/seekProg" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CALCULATE"
    android:id="@+id/btnCalc"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekProg"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekProg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/toggleProg" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Average: No Grade"
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnCalc"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/btnCalc"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/btnCalc"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#2a34f4"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.elijah.comp3labexercise9;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ToggleButton togSci, togMath, togEng, togPro;
SeekBar skSci, skMath, skEng, skPro;
TextView etSci, etMath, etEng, etPro, etRes;
Button calc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    togSci = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.toggleSci);
    togMath = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.toggleMath);
    togEng = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.toggleEng);
    togPro = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.toggleProg);

    skSci = (SeekBar) findViewById (R.id.seekSci);
    skMath = (SeekBar) findViewById (R.id.seekMath);
    skEng = (SeekBar) findViewById (R.id.seekEng);
    skPro = (SeekBar) findViewById (R.id.seekProg);

    etSci = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtSci);
    etMath = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtMath);
    etEng = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtEng);
    etPro = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtProg);
    etRes = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtResult);

    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int countGrd = 0;
            float totalGrd = 0;

            if (togSci.isChecked()) {
                countGrd++;
                totalGrd = totalGrd + skSci.getProgress() + 50;
            }
            if (togEng.isChecked()) {
                countGrd++;
                totalGrd = totalGrd + skEng.getProgress() + 50;
            }
            if (togMath.isChecked()) {
                countGrd++;
                totalGrd = totalGrd + skMath.getProgress() + 50;
            }
            if (togPro.isChecked()) {
                countGrd++;
                totalGrd = totalGrd + skPro.getProgress() + 50;
            }
            if (countGrd == 0) {
                etRes.setText("Average: No Grade");
            }else{
                float ave = totalGrd / countGrd;
                etRes.setText("Average: "+ String.format("%.2f%%" , ave));
            }
        }
    });
}

private void seekbarLisHander() {

    skSci.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int progressChanged = 0;


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
            progressChanged = progress;

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            int grd = progressChanged + 50;
            etSci.setText("Science: " + grd + "%");

        }
    });

    skMath.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int progressChanged = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
            progressChanged = progress + 50;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            int grd = progressChanged + 50;
            etMath.setText("Mathematics: " + grd + "%");

        }
    });

    skEng.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int progressChanged = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
            progressChanged = progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            int grd = progressChanged + 50;
            etEng.setText("English: " + grd + "%");
        }
    });

    skPro.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int progressChanged = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
            progressChanged = progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            int grd = progressChanged + 50;
            etPro.setText("Programming: " + grd + "%");
        }
    });
}
}
```

I hope guys that you can help me and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have set `android:max="50"` to `SeekBar`.

So it will seek max to 50.

Change it to   `android:max="100"`
Now seekbar can seek beetween 0 to 100 . So you have to make logic for `onProgressChanged`.

Comment: `android:max="50"` this is what in your xml

Comment: I need to start the seekbar to 50% not 0%

Comment: Ok lets make it clear . if you start with 50 then how are you expecting it to move further because max is 50 . ? You can not set a anchor progress in SEEkbar . So it will always move from 0% to 100% . Just make it 0 to 100 .and make step as 2.

Comment: Is there another way I can make this to start a t 50% instead of 0%?